# iPad 7 interface with microscope camera

Tags: usb, tablet, apple

I need to interface an AmScope MU1003B 10MP USB3.0 microscope camera to an Apple iPad running iOS 17.1.1. The iPad 7 uses a Lightning jack and the MU1003B uses a USB3-A plug. The Lightning to USB3-A adapter I have is not working.

I have spoken to Logitech, Apple, Google, Bard, etc., and they offer little help.  The adapter needs to be MFi-certified. I need to locate this new piece of adapter hardware.

The MU1003B camera is USB3, the iPad is Lightning and apparently USB2. There may be proprietary hardware or custom USB pin outs in the camera and cable permanently attached to the camera. Can anyone help better define these hardware issues and suggest a hardware work around?

Comment: Hi Whs, welcome to Hardware Recommendations! We tend to focus more on providing recommendations for new hardware, rather than providing support for existing hardware; if you've tried a USB-A to Lightning adapter, that's probably really all we could recommend you here. You may want to try Super User instead, they can probably help you better with debugging. I would recommend also trying a Mac/Windows/Linux device, since that seems to be what's officially supported by AmScope.

Comment: JMY1000: I was directed by EEstk to query Hardware Recommends with this question.  Why do you close out a question that was viewed 11 times before anyone else has a chance to contribute?

Comment: As written the question focuses more on debugging the software for an *existing* hardware setup you have: a specific scope and a iPad 7th generation. Debugging *existing* hardware configurations is out-of-scope for this site, and is more appropriate for Superuser; I'm sorry to hear that the EE stack pointed you here for that type of question, but unfortunately this isn't the right place.

Comment: If you have questions about procuring *new* hardware to fit your use case, please edit your existing post to focus on those aspects. Describe what you're trying to do more broadly with your setup (not just what hardware you have) and what challenges you're facing when deciding what hardware to purchase.

Comment: JMY1000; Thank you for the added guidance. I have a related question on the  software before Software Recommendations. My question here is strictly finding the correct Mfi Lightning to USB3-A adapter hardware for  a live webcam. There is nothing to debug. What is Superuser? Please provide a link and I will see if it helps.

Comment: As suggested, I edited my question. Is this more within scope?

Comment: Looks better. That said, does it need to be a USB 3 adapter? If so, no such device exists, as Lightning is a USB 2 interface.

Comment: The MU1003B camera is USB3, the iPad is Lightning and apparently USB2. There may be proprietary hardware or custom USB pin outs in the camera and cable permanently attached to the camera. Can anyone help better define these hardware issues and suggest a hardware work around?

Comment: There's no workaround. You could use an iPad Pro (2018 or newer) or an iPhone 15 Pro, both of which support USB 3; however, I would *strongly* recommend using a Mac/Windows/Linux device, as that's what's supported. Is there a reason you can't use a Mac/Windows/Linux?

Comment: The intent is to use the iPad for its small size and high screen quality. I have an ACER Switch5 tablet/laptop available, which is a good size format, but the screen quality is not up to this task. Are there windows tablet/laptops with screen quality similar to Apple products? I will look into the iPad Pro line =>2018. Thank you for that suggestion.

Comment: Gotcha. In that case I'd try an iPad Pro (2018 or newer) and [this iPad app](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/genki-studio/id6466343285), which should support all USB UVC capture devices. I haven't fully validated that this particular AmScope scope uses UVC, but several of their other scopes do so I wouldn't be surprised.